# We are using ClearCase version control and need to set up a symlink to seperate versions on seperate branches of a file

Tags: version, clearcase, symlink

We are trying to set up symlinks to a file.

While setting up the symlink is fine how can we point to specific version?
We also want to point to several versions.

For example, in `folder1` we have an upgrade script to go from 7.1 to 7.2 to 7.3 all on different branches.
We want:

- the symlink in `directory 1` to point to the version on the 7.1 branch,
- the symlink in `directory 2` to point to the version on the 7.2 branch and
- the symlink in the `directory 3` to point to the version on the 7.3 branch.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`cleartool ln` command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_ln.htm) contains a character string, the link text, in the form of a path name. That does not include a version or extended path.

As mentioned in "[About Vob links in snapshot views](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/c_symlinks_ssv.htm)"

> If a load rule selects a symbolic link, the link target is copied into the view at the link path.

That illustrates what is copied is whatever version currently selected by the view, not a specific version